# To identify the types of roots

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, factoring, substitution, quartics

If $(x+2)(x+3)(x+8)(x+12)=4x^{2}$ then the equation has what type of roots?

My attempt:
Intersecting the graphs
Can you please suggest any other easy method?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we can write
$$(x+2)(x+3)(x+8)(x+12)-4x^2=(x+4)(x+6)(x^2+15x+24).$$

Also, we can write
$$(x^2+14x+24)(x^2+11x+24)=4x^2$$ or
$$\left(x+\frac{24}{x}+14\right)\left(x+\frac{24}{x}+11\right)=4$$ and after a substitution $x+\frac{24}{x}+11=t$ we can get all roots.

Indeed, we obtain $t^2+3t-4=0,$ which gives $t=1$ or $t=-4$,

For  $x+\frac{24}{x}+11=1$ we obtain $\{-4,-6\}$ and the equation $x+\frac{24}{x}+11=-4$ has two real roots.

Comment: Isn't it too difficult to convert the eqn directly into some other forms.

Comment: I would like to know the mindset behind doing this. Why have you preferred doing that way?

Comment: Because I want equation with a less degree. By this substitution I got a quadratic equation.